# How to decode JSON data sent to server by TripTracker?

Tags: java, android, json

I am using a PHP MySQL server model. I want to decode the JSON data that is sent to the server by this code. Any help would be appreciated. The app sends current GPS coordinates to inputed server as JSON array object. I would like to decode it to share with other android users. Thanks a lot. This is the Android code.

```
public class TrackerService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "TripTracker/Service";

private final String updatesCache = "updates.cache";

public static TrackerService service;

private NotificationManager nm;
private Notification notification;
private static boolean isRunning = false;

private String freqString;
private int freqSeconds;
private String endpoint;

private final int MAX_RING_SIZE = 15;

private LocationListener locationListener;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingAlarm;
private static volatile PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

private AsyncTask httpPoster;

ArrayList<LogMessage> mLogRing = new ArrayList<LogMessage>();
ArrayList<Messenger> mClients = new ArrayList<Messenger>();
ArrayList<List> mUpdates = new ArrayList<List>();
final ReentrantReadWriteLock updateLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

static final int MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT = 1;
static final int MSG_UNREGISTER_CLIENT = 2;
static final int MSG_LOG = 3;
static final int MSG_LOG_RING = 4;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    TrackerService.service = this;

    endpoint = Prefs.getEndpoint(this);
    freqSeconds = 0;
    freqString = null;

    freqString = Prefs.getUpdateFreq(this);
    if (freqString != null && !freqString.equals("")) {
        try {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(m|h|s)");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(freqString);
            m.find();
            freqSeconds = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
            if (m.group(2).equals("h"))
                freqSeconds *= (60 * 60);
            else if (m.group(2).equals("m"))
                freqSeconds *= 60;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    if (endpoint == null || endpoint.equals("")) {
        logText("invalid endpoint, stopping service");
        stopSelf();
    }

    if (freqSeconds < 1) {
        logText("invalid frequency (" + freqSeconds + "), stopping " +
            "service");
        stopSelf();
    }

    readCache();

    showNotification();

    isRunning = true;

    /* we're not registered yet, so this will just log to our ring buffer,
     * but as soon as the client connects we send the log buffer anyway */
    logText("service started, requesting location update every " +
        freqString);

    /* findAndSendLocation() will callback to this */
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            sendLocation(location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
        Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    /* we don't need to be exact in our frequency, try to conserve at least
     * a little battery */
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcast.class);
    pendingAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), freqSeconds * 1000, pendingAlarm);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (httpPoster != null)
        httpPoster.cancel(true);

    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

    /* kill persistent notification */
    nm.cancelAll();

    if (pendingAlarm != null)
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingAlarm);

    isRunning = false;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

/* must be done inside of updateLock */
public void cacheUpdates() {
    OutputStreamWriter cacheStream = null;

    try {
        FileOutputStream cacheFile = TrackerService.this.openFileOutput(
            updatesCache, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        cacheStream = new OutputStreamWriter(cacheFile, "UTF-8");

        /* would be nice to just serialize mUpdates but it's not
         * serializable.  create a json array of json objects, each object
         * having each key/value pair of one location update. */

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < mUpdates.size(); i++) {
            List<NameValuePair> pair = mUpdates.get(i);
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

            for (int j = 0; j < pair.size(); j++) {
                try {
                    jo.put(((NameValuePair)pair.get(j)).getName(),
                        pair.get(j).getValue());
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                }
            }

            ja.put(jo);
        }

        cacheStream.write(ja.toString());
        cacheFile.getFD().sync();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, e);
    }
    finally {
        if (cacheStream != null) {
            try {
                cacheStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

/* read json cache into mUpdates */
public void readCache() {
    updateLock.writeLock().lock();

    InputStreamReader cacheStream = null;

    try {
        FileInputStream cacheFile = TrackerService.this.openFileInput(
            updatesCache);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
        byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = cacheFile.read(bbuf)) != -1)
            buf.append(new String(bbuf));

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(new String(buf));

        mUpdates = new ArrayList<List>();

        for (int j = 0; j < ja.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(j);

            List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

            Iterator<String> i = jo.keys();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                String k = (String)i.next();
                String v = jo.getString(k);

                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair(k, v));
            }

            mUpdates.add(nvp);
        }

        if (mUpdates.size() > 0)
            logText("read " + mUpdates.size() + " update" +
                (mUpdates.size() == 1 ? "" : "s") + " from cache");
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, e);
    }
    finally {
        if (cacheStream != null) {
            try {
                cacheStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    updateLock.writeLock().unlock();
}

/* called within wake lock from broadcast receiver, but assert that we have
 * it so we can keep it longer when we return (since the location request
 * uses a callback) and then free it when we're done running through the
 * queue */
public void findAndSendLocation() {
    if (wakeLock == null) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(
            Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        /* we don't need the screen on */
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "triptracker");
        wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
    }

    if (!wakeLock.isHeld())
        wakeLock.acquire();

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        locationListener, null);
}

public static boolean isRunning() {
    return isRunning;
}

private void showNotification() {
    nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
        "Trip Tracker Started", System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Trip Tracker",
        "Sending location every " + freqString, contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    nm.notify(1, notification);
}

private void updateNotification(String text) {
    if (nm != null) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Trip Tracker", text,
            contentIntent);
        notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        nm.notify(1, notification);
    }
}

public void logText(String log) {
    LogMessage lm = new LogMessage(new Date(), log);
    mLogRing.add(lm);
    if (mLogRing.size() > MAX_RING_SIZE)
        mLogRing.remove(0);

    updateNotification(log);

    for (int i = mClients.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        try {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("log", log);
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MSG_LOG);
            msg.setData(b);
            mClients.get(i).send(msg);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            /* client is dead, how did this happen */
            mClients.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

/* flatten an array of NameValuePairs into an array of
 * locations[0]latitude, locations[1]latitude, etc. */
public List<NameValuePair> getUpdatesAsArray() {
    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

    for (int i = 0; i < mUpdates.size(); i++) {
        List<NameValuePair> pair = mUpdates.get(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < pair.size(); j++)
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locations[" + i + "][" +
                ((NameValuePair)pair.get(j)).getName() + "]",
                pair.get(j).getValue()));
    }

    return pairs;
}

public int getUpdatesSize() {
    return mUpdates.size();
}

public void removeUpdate(int i) {
    mUpdates.remove(i);
}

private void sendLocation(Location location) {
    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time",
        String.valueOf(location.getTime())));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude",
        String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude",
        String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("speed",
        String.valueOf(location.getSpeed())));

    /* push these pairs onto the queue, and only run the poster if another
     * one isn't running already (if it is, it will keep running through
     * the queue until it's empty) */
    updateLock.writeLock().lock();
    mUpdates.add(pairs);
    int size = service.getUpdatesSize();
    cacheUpdates();
    updateLock.writeLock().unlock();

    logText("location " +
        (new DecimalFormat("#.######").format(location.getLatitude())) +
        ", " +
        (new DecimalFormat("#.######").format(location.getLongitude())) +
        (size <= 1 ? "" : " (" + size + " queued)"));

    if (httpPoster == null ||
    httpPoster.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
        (httpPoster = new HttpPoster()).execute();
}

class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_REGISTER_CLIENT:
            mClients.add(msg.replyTo);

            /* respond with our log ring to show what we've been up to */
            try {
                Message replyMsg = Message.obtain(null, MSG_LOG_RING);
                replyMsg.obj = mLogRing;
                msg.replyTo.send(replyMsg);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e) {
            }

            break;
        case MSG_UNREGISTER_CLIENT:
            mClients.remove(msg.replyTo);
            break;

        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}

/* Void as first arg causes a crash, no idea why
E/AndroidRuntime(17157): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Void[]
*/
class HttpPoster extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... o) {
        TrackerService service = TrackerService.service;

        int retried = 0;
        int max_retries = 4;

        while (true) {
            if (isCancelled())
                return false;

            boolean failed = false;

            updateLock.writeLock().lock();
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = service.getUpdatesAsArray();
            int pairSize = service.getUpdatesSize();
            updateLock.writeLock().unlock();

            AndroidHttpClient httpClient =
                AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("TripTracker");

            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(endpoint);
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);

                int httpStatus = resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (httpStatus == 200) {
                    /* all good, we can remove everything we've sent from
                     * the queue (but not just clear it, in case another
                     * one jumped onto the end while we were here) */
                    updateLock.writeLock().lock();
                    for (int i = pairSize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        service.removeUpdate(i);
                    updateLock.writeLock().unlock();
                }
                else {
                    logText("POST failed to " + endpoint + ": got " +
                        httpStatus + " status");
                    failed = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logText("POST failed to " + endpoint + ": " + e);
                Log.w(TAG, e);
                failed = true;
            }
            finally {
                if (httpClient != null)
                    httpClient.close();
            }

            if (failed) {
                /* if our initial request failed, snooze for a bit and try
                 * again, the server might not be reachable */
                SystemClock.sleep(15 * 1000);

                if (++retried > max_retries) {
                    /* give up since we're holding the wake lock open for
                     * too long.  we'll get it next time, champ. */
                    logText("too many failures, retrying later (queue " +
                        "size " + service.getUpdatesSize() + ")");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
                retried = 0;

            int q = 0;
            updateLock.writeLock().lock();
            q = service.getUpdatesSize();
            cacheUpdates();
            updateLock.writeLock().unlock();

            if (q == 0)
                break;
            /* otherwise, run through the rest of the queue */
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
        if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld())
            wakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i don't understand what your problem is. (and your code is waaaaaaaay too long)

Comment: i have difficulty implement a php server to request for the locations

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the data using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php

$json  = ""; // JSON data 

$json_obj = json_decode($json); // As Object 
$json_arr = json_decide($json,true) // As Array

var_dump($json_obj);
print_r($json_arr);
```

// Store Array to database using serialize function

$data = serialize($json_array); // Array will be converted into string

```
?>
```

Comment: i want to decode the JSON into a php array and write to database

Comment: I edit the code, You can use serialize function to store json array in the database, if you want to store json in the database use addslashes() function.

Comment: is there a way i can explain this to you further? are u on skype?